# How can you have per environment configuration for Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-logic-apps

How can you have per environment configuration for Logic Apps?

With API Apps and Function Apps, I can use the Application Settings to hold environment specific values.

But there doesn't seem to be any equivalent in the Logic App blade ?

Appreciate you can set connections to other systems by setting the values of the API Connections, but what about simple things, e.g. I want the subject of an email to depend on an environment specific settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using parameters in your workflow definition. Here you have an example: https://platform.deloitte.com.au/articles/preparing-azure-logic-apps-for-cicd

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables in Dataverse solution could be used. Value can be set per environment and then moved with the Solution between environments. These variables are accessible using Dataverse REST API.

1. First you need to find defintion of the variable to find it's ID in `environmentvariabledefinitions` table
2. Then query `environmentvariablevalues` table for real value per environment

```
GET [Org URI]/api/data/v9.2/environmentvariabledefinitions?$filter=schemaname eq 'prefix_VariableName'&$select=environmentvariabledefinitionid
GET [Org URI]/api/data/v9.2/environmentvariablevalues?$filter=_environmentvariabledefinitionid_value eq {environmentvariabledefinitionid}&$select=value
```

> Reference
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/environmentvariables
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/reference/environmentvariabledefinition
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/reference/environmentvariablevalue